# How to transfer a object from JS to AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I got an JS-object in my index.html namend user. In this object are some user with mail, name etc.

So now I want to use this object in my app.js (AngularJS). I need it there.
I tried to tranfer it like this in my app.js:

```
var tempArr = $scope.user;
```

But it does not work. 
Is there a possibility to transfer it from JS in my index.html to app.js?

Comment: You can't have "a JS object in HTML". It exists in JavaScript only. How is this object defined in `index.html`? Post some code.

Comment: May be by injecting  `window`

Comment: Assign the object to the global variable. You can use a global variable anywhere in the app.

Comment: I just assumed it's a code in a <script> tag, but yet again, it can be something completely else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As You asked From JS to angularjs so anything that is in js is in global window scope of browser and accessible inside angularjs scope so no problem to use a variable from js to angularjs context.

Comment: To add to @yashdeep's answer try below 
app.tempArr = $window.user;

Answer (score 1):

In your, `app.js` you probably have something like

```
var app = angular.module(/*blah blah*/);
```

That same `app` variable should be (made) accessible from the outside i.e. in the global scope. That way you can just write

```
app.tempArr = $scope.user;
```

But, of course, this is just quick and dirty solution. What I usually do is to create one global object, like

```
var GLOBAL = {};
```

and attach everything of mine on it, like

```
GLOBAL.app = angular.module(/*blah blah*/);
GLOBAL.someHelperFunction = function someHelperFunction(){};
```

and even, if needed

```
GLOBAL.tempArr = $scope.user;
// even better if you just clone the user values
// not just attach it to GLOBAL
```